# my code is repeating itself instead of allowing for user input

Tags: c, function

hey i have written a c code that includes various functions however i am having problems at the end of my code. this is the function main of my code

```
int main() {
  do {
    printf("-- Wind turbine power calculator -- \n");

    /*defining variables for each function,
    Cp = performance coefficient,
    Ng = generator efficiency,
    Nb = gearbox efficiency,
    V = velocity,
    hA = horizontal area,
    vA = vertical area,
    d = rotor diameter,
    h = rotor height,
    a = altitude,
    t = type of turbine */

    double t, V, Cp, Ng, Nb, p, Pwr, d, a, h, hA, vA, A;
    char ch, n, y, N, Y;

    t = getType();
    d = getDiameter();
    h = getHeight();
    a = getAltitude();
    V = getVelocity();
    Cp = getPerformance();
    Ng = getGenerator();
    Nb = getGearbox();
    p = density(a);
    hA = hArea(d);
    vA = vArea(d, h);

    /*setting the area in the power equation to equal the calculated vertical or horizontal area depending on the input from user*/

    if (t == 'v' || t == 'V') {
      A = vA;
    } else if (t == 'h' || t == 'H') {
      A = hA;
    }

    /*calculating the power of the wind turbine calling on the functions within the code*/

    Pwr = A * p * Cp * 0.5 * Ng * Nb * V * V * V;

    printf("The turbine power is %0.0lf KW\n", Pwr);

    /*asking the user if they want to continue the program, if not the program will end*/

    printf("\nDo you want to continue (y/n):");
    scanf("%c", & ch);

    if (ch == 'n' || ch == 'N')
      break;
    printf("\nThe program has been terminated\n");
  }while (1);

  return 0;
}
```

I'm having problems with the last part

```
 /*asking the user if they want to continue the program, if not the program will end*/

    printf("\nDo you want to continue (y/n):");
    scanf("%c", & ch);

    if (ch == 'n' || ch == 'N')
      break;
    printf("\nThe program has been terminated\n");
  }while (1);

  return 0;
}
```

when the code comes to this part it just automatically repeats itself and does not allow the user to enter its input and then decide if it should run again or terminate.

any ideas on how to fix this?? i think one way might be to do with the scanf property but I'm not 100% sure.

thankyou for the help

Comment: Did you read the trailing newline from the last scanf? Easy fix: change `"%c"` to `" %c"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are encountering is that you have not cleared the input buffer.

So when you used `scanf("%c", &ch);`, it did not get the key you just typed but a key you typed before that.

This key may be typed last time you checked if they wanted to continue the program, or in one of your functions.

Anyway, the solution is to write `fflush(stdin);` before you get input.

Also, have you noticed that your bracket at the end of your if statement was not matched?
That would not correspond to your problem so I just assumed it was a mistake when you asked the question.

And your indentation is really annoying, it took me way too long to understand your code.